# Bootstrap 4: external navbar content responsiveness issue

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have a Boostrap 4 navbar in Angular application with an external `<div>` associated. With BS3 everithing works like a charms, but with BS4 some behaviors seems to be changed. In particular i'm having trouble with the `.collapse` class.
With BS3 when i load the page the external div is shown, but with BS4 it's initially hidden. Moreover with BS3 when i resize the page the exernal div is automatically collapsed together with the navbar, whereas with BS4 it is not.

So my question is: what do i have to do to have the same exact behavior i had with Boostrap 3?

Here is my code:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light px-0 py-0 mb-5">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header" style="width: 100%">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler pull-right my-2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="pull-left">
            <img src="assets/images/image.png" width="200" height="100">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="btn welcome"> Benvenuto <strong>{{ this.sessionUsername }}</strong>!</a></li>                         
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="btn link" role="button" [routerLink]="['/login']" (click)="clearSessionStorage()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="btn link" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#changePasswordModal"><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> Cambio Password</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    === External div that give me troubles in responsiveness ===
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" style="float: left">  
      <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
          <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="session.isCompanyVisible"><a class="nav-link link" [routerLink]="['./company']"><i class="fa fa-building-o"></i> Società </a></li>
          <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="session.isDocTypeVisible"><a class="nav-link link" [routerLink]="['./document-type']"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> Tipo Documento </a></li>
          <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="session.isConfigVisible"><a class="nav-link link" [routerLink]="['./configuration']"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Configurazione </a></li>
          <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="session.isDomainsVisible"><a class="nav-link link" [routerLink]="['./domains']"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Domini </a></li>
          <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="session.isSignTypeVisible"><a class="nav-link link" [routerLink]="['./signature-type']"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Firme </a></li>
          <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="session.isMonitoringVisible"><a class="nav-link link" [routerLink]="['./monitoring']"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> Monitoraggio </a></li>
          <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="session.isPDAManagementVisible"><a class="nav-link link" [routerLink]="['./pda-management']"><i class="fa fa-mobile fa-lg"></i> Gestione PDA </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where and how *exactly* do you want the contents of the external div to be shown on the initial page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of change in bootstarp's css 
So you can solve your issue by apply some css to your external div as i applied in snippet

```css
 @media (min-width: 992px){
      .external-collapse.navbar-collapse {
          display: -webkit-box!important;
          display: -ms-flexbox!important;
          display: flex!important;
      }
  }
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light px-0 py-0 mb-5">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header" style="width: 100%">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler pull-right my-2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="pull-left">
                <img src="assets/images/image.png" width="200" height="100">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="btn welcome"> Benvenuto <strong>{{ this.sessionUsername }}</strong>!</a></li>                         
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="btn link" role="button" [routerLink]="['/login']" (click)="clearSessionStorage()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="btn link" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#changePasswordModal"><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> Cambio Password</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    === External div that give me troubles in responsiveness ===
    <div class="external-collapse navbar-collapse collapse col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" style="float: left">  
        <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="session.isCompanyVisible"><a class="nav-link link" [routerLink]="['./company']"><i class="fa fa-building-o"></i> Società </a></li>
            <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="session.isDocTypeVisible"><a class="nav-link link" [routerLink]="['./document-type']"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> Tipo Documento </a></li>
            <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="session.isConfigVisible"><a class="nav-link link" [routerLink]="['./configuration']"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Configurazione </a></li>
            <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="session.isDomainsVisible"><a class="nav-link link" [routerLink]="['./domains']"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Domini </a></li>
            <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="session.isSignTypeVisible"><a class="nav-link link" [routerLink]="['./signature-type']"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Firme </a></li>
            <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="session.isMonitoringVisible"><a class="nav-link link" [routerLink]="['./monitoring']"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> Monitoraggio </a></li>
            <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="session.isPDAManagementVisible"><a class="nav-link link" [routerLink]="['./pda-management']"><i class="fa fa-mobile fa-lg"></i> Gestione PDA </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank youvery much @nidhi. That css solved my problems!